# How to add event tracking to a Javascript alert

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, analytics, alerts

I have a very basic wesbite that is literally just 4 hyperlinks, i'm experimenting with bounce rate and i'm trying to add an event to a javascript alert I have, so that when the "ok" button is click on the alert it counts that event and is no longer a page bounce.

```
<?php
session_start();?>
    <script>
       setTimeout(function(){ alert("Are you still viewing the page?"); }, 30000) 
    </script>
<?php
```

This is the code I currently have, I understand the layout to do this is similar to something like this  ga('send','event','click');

But I can't figure out where I need to place this code and if I have entered the right details to track this, everytime I place this code in certain place it breaks Google analytics and no longer tracks the site or it break my pop up.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably place it on the button itself, so something like `<button onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'click', 'OK button');" .... >";`. You've got the event category, but you'll also need the action.

Comment: Something like this?      <button onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'click', 'OK button');" setTimeout(function(){ alert("Are you still viewing the page?"); }, 30000)>";  The only issue is it isn't really an OK button it is just a standard alert that has "ok" I don't really have anywhere that is it classified as a button or anything like that its literally just the alert code shown.

Comment: Major companies use Google Tag Manager for a lot of their event tracking. If you are learning google analytics, I strongly suggest spending some time with GTM.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misread. You want to track the JS alert OK button itself. Actually,  I don't think that's possible. You could try to send the event when you create the alert itself though.

Comment: You could leave out the alert and simply send an event after the timeout. That would be a lot less annoying than looking at a question that I have to answer with "ok" if I want to be able to use my browser again.

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case it is better to use confirm() method instead of alert().

Example:

```
var r = confirm("Are you still viewing the page?");
if (r == true) {
    //whatever you want to do
}
```

Comment: To add a bit of reasoning: It is pointless to ask a yes/not question to an alert, since the alert a) is blocking the window, b) allows only for one answer ("ok").  The purpose of the alert is simply to prevent users from doing anything else, so it does not offer any interaction except closing it. If you want ask questions you have to use confirm since it allows for yes/no answers.

Comment: The wording is off because I am just experimenting myself, so yeah I suppose I should have put something different, perhaps "click ok to confirm you are still viewing this page." or similar. as the idea is to see if they are still on the page or if they have left the page before the alert appears. The confirm idea looks good so I will experiment with that.